# How to make elements float left outside viewport?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm making this slideshow of images. The container is holding 4 elements. The 4th element is supposed to continue outside of the border so that it makes the illusion of infinite scrolling. How do I keep the elements "stacked" from the left side of the screen to a bit beyond the right side?

Maybe you get a better idea if you see what I mean: https://gyazo.com/20ef49b4bd1987baf421e92824e82cb1

Two elements are the same.

Html:

```
<section class="photo-grid-slideshow">
    <div class="photo-crop">
        <h3>With you
            <div class="xs-spacer"></div>
            <a class="med-btn btn-white">Read more</a>
        </h3>
        <div class="photo-grid-container" style="background-image: url('Images and videos/odesza2.png');"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="photo-crop">
        <h3>I wanna
            <div class="xs-spacer"></div>
            <a class="med-btn btn-white">Read more</a>
        </h3>
        <div class="photo-grid-container" style="background-image: url('Images and videos/odesza1.jpg');"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="photo-crop">
        <h3>Dance
            <div class="xs-spacer"></div>
            <a class="med-btn btn-white">Read more</a>
        </h3>
        <div class="photo-grid-container" style="background-image: url('Images and videos/odesza3.jpg');"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="photo-crop">
        <h3>With you
            <div class="xs-spacer"></div>
            <a class="med-btn btn-white">Read more</a>
        </h3>
        <div class="photo-grid-container" style="background-image: url('Images and videos/odesza2.png');"></div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Css:

```
.photo-grid-slideshow {
    height: 300px;
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    background: black;
    padding: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #444;
}

.photo-crop {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
    width: calc(100% / 3);
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Script:

```
$(function(){
setInterval(function(){
        $(".photo-grid-slideshow .photo-crop:first-of-type").animate({marginLeft: "-=421px"}, 2000, "linear", function(){
            $(this).css("margin-left", 0).appendTo('.photo-grid-slideshow');
        })
    }, 2500);
});
```

Comment: need to provide enough code and html structure for us to help. Image is only helpful for expected results, not to troubleshoot from

Comment: It looks like you should copy the last picture(which is hiding on the left side) and place at the beginning. You can use prepend/append.
If its plugin you are using, then he should have something like onSlide event. If its made by you, just call "copy function" every time slider switch elements :).

Comment: probably by using inline-blocks while forcing the parent to keep a single line (no linebreak) and `overflow: hidden`

Comment: @charlietfl Edit has the code.

Comment: the code you provided already does that job???

Comment: @Aziz on the left side yes. Cant figure out how to make it do so on the right side.

Comment: @charlietfl Prefer to not clone so I dont have to delete elements. There is enough elements to make it viable anyway.

Comment: Actually no. It did solve what I asked for in the initial question but not my problem. I'm new here so please help me out. Should I still accept and upvote your answer?

Answer (score 0):

You may do it, using negative values for the `margin-left` and a large value for the `width` of your `ul` like this:

```css
body{
  background-color: #EFEFEF;
}
.container{
  overflow: hidden;
}
.list{
  margin-left: -80px;
  list-style: none;
  width: 9999px;
  height: 160px;
  background-color: #FFDDDD;
}
.list li{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #CDCDFF;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul class="list">
    <li>This is the first item</li>  
    <li>This is the first item</li>  
    <li>This is the first item</li>  
    <li>This is the first item</li>  
    <li>This is the first item</li>  
    <li>This is the first item</li>  
    <li>This is the first item</li>  
    <li>This is the first item</li>  
  </ul>
</div>
```

### UPDATE

After you edited your question, I added this update to cover the new question:

```
$(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
        var p = $(".photo-grid-slideshow .photo-crop").css('width');
        $(".photo-grid-slideshow .photo-crop:first-of-type").animate({marginLeft: '-=' + p}, 4000, "linear", function(){
            $(this).css("margin-left", 0).appendTo('.photo-grid-slideshow');
        })
    }, 2500);
});
```

Comment: Yes, but in my example it needs to be put on the right side of the screen specifically. In other words: the leftmost object should move to the left with the three others to the right.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer, although that didn't seem to work either. If you bare with me til the end I'll be very happy. :) Here's what it looks like now: https://gyazo.com/f8533b0e96a2219d759c76508b0f2098

(Made the container overflow: visible; so that you can see what is happening)

Comment: Keep in mind, after final explanations you made, I added the UPDATE section, so forget about the first part of the answer and just substitute the JS part with yours and it will work

Comment: Sorry sir. I did try the code in the update section. This is the result: https://gyazo.com/37b0d869c074584dadcf5d80ce9c6b3a

The elements are supposed to align on the left side of the viewport and stack outside. Visual: http://1.1m.yt/URz9d1v.png